# sass not compiling my media directives

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

Here's my sass file:

```
@import 'reset';
@import 'page';
@import 'colors';
@import 'typography';

$screen-xs:                  480px !default;
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
//there are more of these for each screen size: sm, md, lg

@media (min-width: $screen-xs-min) {
  .thumbnail img { 
    height:64px !important;
  }
}
//there are more of these @media queries, for each screen-<size>-min one
```

all seems to compile well except that all the @media queries compile to empty `{}` blocks. 
Excerpt of the compiled file:

```
h1.bottom{font-weight:bold;color:#03bbc1;margin-top:-8px !important}@media (min-width: 480px){}@media (min-width: 768px){}@media (min-width: 992px){}@media (min-width: 1200px){}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using nodejs, and grunt for compiling scss files. grunt reports the following when I change the file:

```
>> File "sass/styles.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File public/css/styles.css created.
File public/css/styles.css.map created.

Done, without errors.
```

So all seems fine...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, there's a problem with your compiler:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/4a1bf577ac941209d925

Answer (score 0):

grunt sass uses libsass that is not dependent on ruby gems so it will compile faster but has this problem with media queries when compiling with the `outputStyle` compressed. You can change the `outputStyle` to `nested` and it will work.

I know that's not good for production sites! You could use grunt contrib sass, as this does work with media queries when compressing, but it will be very slow to compile big scss files with many includes as it runs on ruby gems.

I have experimented with using grunt sass to compile the sass as nested and then using grunt cssmin task to minify the nested output.  But this seems to have problems, and I can't see what it might be as its all ugly css at this stage.

Please post back if you find a better way to do this.

update,  found this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/issues/152

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question being asked at all.

Comment: i think you will find it has everything todo with it. if you actually read the git hub issue that i posted the link to you will find that there is a solution to the problem and everything i was writing about is also discussed as symptoms of the problem that the original poster was asking about. :D please up vote  my solution.

Answer (score -1):

This article gave me the hint:

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32

basically create the media queries inside the classes, not the other way around